# JavaScript: perform action on window resize, only if a CSS style has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(".gallery-container").css("position") === "fixed" ){
    $(".pd-text").removeAttr("style");
  };
});
```

I would like to perform the action only if, on window resize, `.gallery-container` went from `position: relative` to `position: fixed` (which is when the screen size has a `min-width` of 650px).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `console.log($(".gallery-container").css("position"))` and see what you are getting..?

Comment: You possibly need to use a `setTimeout()` of a couple ms... to ensure your condition is evaluated after the `position` property has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your real condition is the MediaQuery `min-width: 650px`, use the [MediaQuery](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) API:

```js
var query = matchMedia('(min-width: 650px)');
query.onchange = updateState; // will trigger when the query status change
updateState();

function updateState(){
  state.textContent = 'background is ' + (query.matches ? 'green' : 'red');
}
```

```css
.rect{
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 650px) {
  .rect {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Run the snippet in 'full page' and resize your window</h3>
<pre id="state"></pre>
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: @Sophie no I can not see from here.. How you did *combine* it with your code? Could you share a jsfiddle? (With this approach you don't need `resize` anymore.)

Comment: Sorry, I feel like your code only checks if, on resize, the window has a `min-width` of 650px. What I need is: if my window was `min-width: 650px` AND on resize it is not `min-width: 650px` anymore, do this.

Comment: @Sophie the `onchange` event will trigger when the MediaQuery `matches` value change. This means that you don't need to listen for the `resize` event yourself, you can only listen to the MQ's onchange. You can try my code in the snippet, click "run in full page" and resize your window, you'll see the text is updated, even though I don't listen to the resize event. Now if you have trouble implementing it, give me a jsfiddle with your try so I can help further.